# Command-line ZIP client

Tags: ssh, centos, compression

Using the zip command, how do I add all files in the current directory to a zip file without including the folder?

For instance, when I unzip, I want all the files to dump out, not get put into a new folder.

I tried

```
zip * file.zip
```

But could not locate the zip file after it was done.

Comment: You should edit this to include what OS you're doing this on. Also, remove the SSH - it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Also FYI - on any Unix-like system (including Linux), if you type "man command-name", you can get the man page (manual) for the command. "man zip" would answer this for you. Not to say you shouldn't ask questions here, but you can get the easy answers fastest from the system itself and you'll learn a lot, too.

Comment: In general, if you don't know how to use a command, type `command --help` or `man command`. In this case `zip --help` or `man zip`. Man as in manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

`zip file.zip *`

Notice how the arguments are backwards compared to your original example.

Answer (score 2):

Create file.zip:

```
zip file *
```